Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^2<+\infty$.
Let $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of complex numbers satisfying the following condition: for any sequence of complex numbers $(y_n)_{n\geq1}$, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|y_n|^2<\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_ny_n|<\infty$.
Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^2<+\infty$.
My approach: Assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^2 = +\infty$. I want to find a suitable $y_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_ny_n| = \infty$. But I don't know where to begin.
